# SimRank on a weighted directed graph (how to calculate node similarity)

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, adjacency-matrix, sparse-matrices

I have a weighted directed graph (it's sparse, 35,000 nodes and 19 million edges) and would like to calculate similarity scores for pairs of nodes. [SimRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimRank#Basic_SimRank_equation) would be ideal for this purpose, except that it applies to unweighted graphs.

It's easy to adapt the matrix representation of SimRank to use weighted edges:

$\mathbf{S} = \max\{C \cdot (\mathbf{A}^T \cdot \mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{A}),\mathbf{I}\}$

Just replace the entries in the adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with the edge weights. But I don't see how to derive the "iteration to a fixed-point" method from this formula.

$s_{k+1}(a, b) = \frac{C}{\left|I(a)\right|\left|I(b)\right|} \cdot \sum_{i \in I(a)} \sum_{j \in I(b)} s_{k}(i, j)$

Is the following method correct?

$s_{k+1}(a, b) = C \cdot \sum_{i \in I(a)} \sum_{j \in I(b)} s_{k}(i, j) \cdot w(i, a) \cdot w(j, b)$

My reasoning is that the original method is equivalent to this:

$s_{k+1}(a, b) = C \cdot \sum_{i \in I(a)} \sum_{j \in I(b)} s_{k}(i, j) \cdot \frac{1}{\left|I(a)\right|} \cdot \frac{1}{\left|I(b)\right|}$

so I replaced the trivially equal weights with the actual ones I have. Confirmation would be nice, though.

If there is a superior method to SimRank, I would like to hear about it. (I'm concerned with improvements to accuracy, not performance; this is a small data set.)

Edit: A different similarity metric that's nearly as accurate but performs a lot better would actually be useful too. My initial tests of SimRank are very slow, and the potential optimizations are not simple to code.

Comment: What similarity specifically do you want to compute?

Comment: The nodes are users and the edges are "favorites" given by one user to another's comments. I want to eventually use a similarity measure between users to apply k-means and find clusters of very similar users. For now I need a good metric, and weighted SimRank looks appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper ["SimRank++: Query Rewriting through Link Analysis of the Click Graph"](http://dbpubs.stanford.edu/pub/showDoc.Fulltext?lang=en&doc=2008-17&format=pdf&compression=&name=2008-17.pdf) describes a weighted SimRank algorithm that is similar to my attempt. It uses this formula to update similarity scores:

$s_{k+1}(a, b) = \text{evidence}(a, b) \cdot C \cdot \sum_{i \in I(a)} \sum_{j \in I(b)} s_{k}(i, j) \cdot w(i, a) \cdot w(j, b) \cdot \text{spread}(i) \cdot \text{spread}(j)$

$\text{evidence}(a, b) = \sum_{i=1}^{\left|I(a) \cap I(b)\right|} \frac{1}{2^i}$

$\text{spread}(i) = e^{-\text{Var}(\{w(i, a) ~|~ a \in O(i)\})}$

Note that the weights should be normalized to sum to 1, which I was already doing. SimRank++ also incorporates evidence scores (which account for the quantity of incoming edges) and spread (which accounts for variance of outgoing edge weights).